# How it is getting the same prefix and suffix?

Tags: algorithm, math, bit-manipulation

I saw this code [here](https://www.quora.com/Given-a-file-containing-4-30-billion-32-bit-integers-how-can-we-find-a-number-which-has-appeared-at-least-twice) and I want to know how below code is working. I understood the logic but just wondering how the implementation used the nice bit logic.

I have modified the code to make it for 4 bit. I wanted to know how common prefix is detected i.e. in the below case 5? What is the mathematical reasoning behind line number 12 and 13?

```
       1     import random
       2     #suppose the range of number is 8 bits
       3     #and we are working with 4bits prefix
       4     #and 4bits suffix
       5     data = []
       6     bits = 4
       7     for i in range(100000):
       8            data.append(random.randint(0, 100))
       9     suffix = 5
       10    for i in data:
       11             i = int(i)
       12             s = i^(suffix<<bits)
       13             if s < (1 << bits):
       14                     print("s is ", s, "prefix of", i, "is", s, "and suffix is ", suffix)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bits == 4
prefix == 5 == 00000101
prefix << bits == 01010000
suffix = i XOR 01010000
    => e.g. if i == 0101xxxx => suffix == 0000xxxx (correct prefix)
    => e.g. if i == 1110xxxx => suffix == 1011xxxx (wrong prefix)
1 << bits == 00010000
if (suffix < 00010000) ~ if (suffix is like 0000xxxx) ~ if (i is like 0101xxxx)
```

So each random number is xor's with the prefix; this is then used both to check which numbers have the right prefix (if the 4 first bits are now 0000) and to get the suffix (last 4 bits).

Comment: just wondering how come you got it so fast? I spent a lot of time to figure it out. Once you answer this i will mark it correct.Oh now i understand I was using ^ as power of not xor.

Comment: @nomanpouigt Yes, the page you linked to is a bit confusing because the explanation uses ^ for powers but the code uses it for xor. It's a common source of confusion, because it's used differently in different languages.